# Confusion about Chrome Apps

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to wrap my head around the different types of Chrome apps and I'm struggling a bit.

I understand there was an old packaged app system that is being depreciated, but I'm confused about hosted apps and "Chrome Apps".

- hosted app: uses a manifest.json file to point to a hosted HTML5 application
- "Chrome App": This looks like a packaged app, but aren't they being phased out? [This](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) page talks about an app that is all bundled up (packaged) so I'm really confused.

Are the "Chrome Apps" new and fully supported packaged apps (and not being phased out in 2015)?

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is legitimate.

The term *Packaged Apps* refers to two versions of *Packaged Apps* in time.

- In 2010 Google introduced *Packaged Apps*.
- In August 2012 Google introduced *Chrome Apps*
- In November 2012 *Packaged Apps* became *Legacy Packaged Apps* due to the confusion between *Chrome Apps* and *Legacy Packaged Apps* both being called by the community as **Packaged Apps**

*Chrome Apps* are from concept equal to *Packaged Apps*, the differences lies beneath the API's (and some other things as well as security). [Quoting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps) from Google's docs

> legacy packaged apps could use most of the extension APIs, but since
>   November 2012, the feature set of legacy packaged apps was reduced

So when referring to *Packaged Apps*, it should refer to the *Legacy Packaged Apps* which will be removed from chrome as of Juli 2015. When referring to *Chrome Apps*, its the newer version of *Packaged Apps* where you could say that *Chrome Apps* evolved out of *Packaged Apps*.

Marketing has clearly failed on this subject, the community clearly see's no difference when using the Term *Packaged Apps* because the standard question on SO is mostly

> When you mean *Packaged Apps*, do you mean *Legacy Packaged Apps* or *Chrome Apps*?

[Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) have nothing to do with Chrome Apps, from development process they seem very narrative but Chrome Extension's purpose is extending functionality of the Chrome Browser, wherein a Chrome Apps's purpose is to pretend to be a native (stand-alone) Application.